# pod install failing after adding firebase_in_app_messaging

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-in-app-messaging

**Failing pod install after adding firebase_in_app_messaging to project**

```
firebase_messaging: ^14.7.5
firebase_core: ^2.23.0
firebase_in_app_messaging: ^0.7.4+5
firebase_database: ^10.3.5
firebase_core_platform_interface: ^5.0.0
```

***Result***

```
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_database: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_in_app_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.18.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Database":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/Database (= 10.2.0)

  In Podfile:
    firebase_database (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_database/ios`) was resolved to 10.3.5, which depends on
      Firebase/Database (= 10.18.0)


You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/Database` inside your development pod `firebase_database`.
   You should run `pod update Firebase/Database` to apply changes you've made.
```

***flutter doctor***

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.0, on macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-arm64, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.3.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```